# How to Automatically Add and Rename Objects in Lua?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to construct a method that automatically adds and renames objects in Lua. I have the add method for adding the object, but I am not sure how to make it so that it renames each object. I'm thinking of adding an `if` statement, but I don't know how to construct it in a way that it will rename the object each type it loops.

Here is what I have so far:

```
frogBody = {density = .8, friction = 0.3, bounce = 0.1, radius = 10} -- body Type
local onPlayerSpawnObject = function(object) -- method to spawn object
      local layer = map:getTileLayer("Enemies")
      local frog = movieclip.newAnim{ "FrogMini.png", "frogMiniRed.png" } -- object that spawns
      frog.x = object.x ; frog.y = object.y
      frog.myName = "frog"
      frog.isHit = false
      physics.addBody(frog, frogBody)
end
```

Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: I think we need more information here. What do you intend to accomplish by renaming? How would this be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you mean is that you would like to access the frogs objects from your example distinctively ?

If that is the case you could either assign the return of the add function to a lua table, or directly assign to the table inside your function.

```
local frogs = {}
frogBody = {density = .8, friction = 0.3, bounce = 0.1, radius = 10} -- body Type
local onPlayerSpawnObject = function(object) -- method to spawn object
    local layer = map:getTileLayer("Enemies")
    local frog = movieclip.newAnim{ "FrogMini.png", "frogMiniRed.png" } -- object that spawns
    frog.x = object.x ; frog.y = object.y
    frog.myName = "frog"
    frog.isHit = false
    physics.addBody(frog, frogBody)
    table.insert(frogs, frog)
end

-- To print a distinct frog from the collection, replace 1 by your index
print (frogs[1].myName)
```